# Retrieve innerhtml of updating soundcloud div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, google-chrome-extension, soundcloud

I am creating a Chrome Extension and am currently trying to retrieve the status of the timer in a Soundcloud page.

Using Firebug I found the element is a div and has a class of "timeIndicator__current".
I attempted to retrieve the element using the following jQuery command.

```
console.log($('.timeIndicator__current').html)
```

I got the following javascript in return.

```
function (e){return v.access(this,function(e){var n=this[0]||{},r=0,i=this.length;if(e===t)return n.nodeType===1?n.innerHTML.replace(ht,""):t;if(typeof e=="string"&&!yt.test(e)&&(v.support.htmlSerialize||!wt.test(e))&&(v.support.leadingWhitespace||!pt.test(e))&&!Nt[(vt.exec(e)||["",""])[1].toLowerCase()]){e=e.replace(dt,"<$1></$2>");try{for(;r<i;r++)n=this[r]||{},n.nodeType===1&&(v.cleanData(n.getElementsByTagName("*")),n.innerHTML=e);n=0}catch(s){}}n&&this.empty().append(e)},null,e,arguments.length)}
```

I have tried using .text,.innerhtml and .val and none seem to give me the current value of the timer, they return either javascript or undefined.

I have also tried waiting till the page has loaded using $(document).ready(function() as well as using the following two commands and have found no solution.

```
$('.timeIndicator playing').find('.timeIndicator__current').html
$('.timeIndicator__total').clone()).html
```

Any help is much appreciated.

**Update:** By request please find my content script below

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*://*.soundcloud.com/*"],
        "js": ["popup.js"]
    }],
```

Comment: `.innerHTML` and `.html()`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the extension do?

Comment: Share your content scripts code!

Comment: @Sudarshan I have added my content script to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Change `.html` to `.html()`

```
console.log($('.timeIndicator__current').html())
```

Comment: It does indeed. Thinking about it, that should've been a comment on OP ;)

Comment: ArvindBhardwaj & @Jimbo Thank you for the fast responses! I tried "console.log($('.timeIndicator__current').html())" and "console.log($('.timeIndicator__current').innerhtml)" but both return undefined in the console. Any other suggestions? I appreciate your help :)